# How to convert from "universal character name" to a sequence of wchar_t's?

Tags: c++, c++11, winapi, unicode, utf-16

In my application I need to be able to parse string literals supported by C++14 standard. So I'm reading [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/string-and-character-literals-cpp?view=vs-2017) on the subject and I'm trying to understand, how do I convert from a `universal character name` to a sequence of `wchar_t`s?

Let me explain with this example. Say, if I compile the following with VS 2017:

```
const wchar_t* str2 = L"\U0001F609 is ;-)";
```

`str2` becomes the following sequence of bytes in memory:

[image]

So how did `\U0001F609` become `3d d8 09 de`? Or, what WinAPI do I need to make this conversion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how did `\U0001F609` become `3d d8 09 de`?

`wchar_t` is 16-bit on windows, but `0x1F609 > UINT16_MAX`, therefore so-called surrogate pairs are used to encode the code point into two code units of 16-bit each.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U+010000_to_U+10FFFF):

- 0x10000 is subtracted from the code point, leaving a 20-bit number in
  the range 0x00000–0xFFFFF. (`0x1F609 - 0x10000 = 0xF609`)
- The high ten bits (in the range 0x000–0x3FF) are added to 0xD800 to
  give the first 16-bit code unit or high surrogate, which will be in
  the range 0xD800–0xDBFF. (`0xD800 + 0x3D`)
- The low ten bits (also in the range 0x000–0x3FF) are added to 0xDC00
  to give the second 16-bit code unit or low surrogate, which will be
  in the range 0xDC00–0xDFFF. (`0xDC00 + 0x209`)

Which leaves `0xD83D 0xDE09`. Encoding this as two little endian 16-bit code units gives `3D D8 09 DE`.

> how do I convert from a universal character name to a sequence of wchar_ts?

The 'Universal character name' is a unicode code point. The `wchar_t` on windows is UTF-16.

> What WinAPI do I need to make this conversion?

I don't know if there are any APIs specifically for that, but it's quite easy to write your own UTF-32<sup>*</sup> to UTF-16 converter. Check the Wikipedia page for more information

---

*: Because 32-bit is big enough to contain all of unicode, every code point can be encoded in one UTF-32 code unit.

Comment: Oh, wow. Really cool. I just learned something,Thanks. Btw, to understand it, it helped me to draw out the bit-masks for this operation. (Otherwise it's hard to do the bitshift in the high surrogate in your head.)

Comment: @c00000fd Ye, I did too, but omitted here for brevity. :)

Comment: in C# there's [`ConvertToUtf32(Char, Char)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.converttoutf32?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: @phuclv: Oh, nice. Btw, [here' s a little graphic](https://i.imgur.com/fqEtgHr.png) for conversion I was talking about.

Comment: According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/wstring_convert, `std::codecvt_utf16<char32_t>` can be used to convert between UTF-32 and UTF-16 on the Windows platform (ignore the _"deprecated in C++17"_, the class will be available aslong as the standard doesn't provide a suitable replacement).

Comment: @zet: Wishful thinking, unfortunately. Deprecation [was applied to C++17](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/p0636r0.html). Visual Studio 2017 will issue deprecation warnings when used. With this, you are at the mercy of the vendor of your compiler(s). Any compliant implementation is free to drop support in C++17 mode.

Comment: @IInspectable It seems to be the disadvantage of a faster advancing standard, that there is also more deprecation. May I suggest an alternative like [boost.locale](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/locale/doc/html/charset_handling.html). Here is a [code sample](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/91e33dc1c2785968) for UTF-32 to UTF-16 conversion.

Comment: @IInspectable no, a conforming implementation is not permitted to drop support of `codecvt_utf16` in C++17 (or in C++20 so far)

Comment: @cub: True, deprecation doesn't equate to removal. Still, this is a first, in that a feature was deprecated, without *any* replacement strategy. We are left with deprecation warnings, and nothing we can do about it, unless we are willing to pull in a dependency on a 3rd party library. That's not generally an option, particularly for library authors.

Comment: @IInspectable this is a second.  std::strstream was deprecated in C++98 with no replacement strategy.  A replacement is only now being considered (a combination of p0448 and p0408). It might make C++23.

Comment: @cub: C++98 was the *initial* C++ Language Standard. Deprecating a pre-standard (i.e. non-standard) feature is a different story.